# Slow Wordpress website?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, performance, woocommerce

My website is crazily slow. Load time: 7.12 s, Page size 3.5 MB. Why is the page size so large? There's only text and an image (118kb) on there. It runs on X theme, and I do have a few heavy plugins installed (e.g., WooCommerce), but need it for the website's purpose.

What can I do to speed up the website? Changing the host is not an option at the moment. I used a caching plugin (W3 Total Cache) in the past, but it doesn't seem to work with PowerPress.

```
Server environment (from Woocommerce)
Server info:        Apache/2
PHP version:        7.0.15
PHP post max size:      20 MB
PHP time limit:     120
PHP max input vars:     5000
cURL version:       7.22.0, GnuTLS/2.12.14
SUHOSIN installed:      –
MySQL version:      5.6.33
Max upload size:        20 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

Look for plugin that could be generating "Big Queries", many a time i have seen free and paid theme/plugin call functions that aren't necessary and generate extra unnecessary queries typical case sometimes they call `in_category` when `is_category` is more than enough.

Also running a profiling tool can help you determine which plugin could be at fault. And general server monitoring can help determine if there is a lack of resources.

A caching solution is always great but like mention in my first line it will not help you from bad code. Sometimes bad code or non-optimal code may actually break the caching thus rendering it useless.

You can also look for a hosting solution that is dedicated instead of shared, shared solution often go the extra mile to save up resources giving you an inconsistent experience. (But that can depend on the scale you are aiming for)

Serving your assets (css,js,images) through a CDN can also increase pageload performance.

> More on the subject : http://www.wpbeginner.com/wordpress-performance-speed/

Answer (score 1):

Such long loading time and such big page size mean that you necessarily should start using good caching plugin. Maybe you should also change your theme to more lightweight one, and maybe you should find some alternative plugins to those which you have installed.

Personally, I had a site which was taking 6.4s to be fully loaded, and its size was equal to 1.26 MB.
I managed to reduce that site's loading time to ~1 second and reduce its size to ~300 KB.
Here's my step-by-step guide how I've achieved such good results:
https://www.alivebetter.com/alivebetters-speed-optimization/

My guide was recently featured in the documentation of Jupiter X WordPress theme (https://themes.artbees.net/docs/optimizing-jupiter-x-to-get-the-maximum-speed/), so I think it's a quite useful piece of work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Caching plugin is a must to increase speed of your site. If it is not working with any other plugin/theme you need to contact plugin author or fix them yourself. Apart from this you need to reduce page size, you can use https://tools.pingdom.com/ to understand where exactly issue is.

If after trying above solutions doesn't solves all your issues, than you need to implement cloud flare and further need to reduce load speed.